# Custom XML Document Content Type with ASP.NET Forms in MOSS 2007/WSS 3.0

Tags: xml, content-type, asp.net

I'd like to create a custom content type in SharePoint 2007 (WSS 3.0) that inherits from the existing XML Document content type (i.e. an InfoPath form) but I want to use custom ASP.NET forms to edit the XML. Is this possible and, if so, how?